# Using GroovyDSL with @TypeChecked in IntelliJ IDEA: Build Project fails

Tags: intellij-idea, groovy, dsl, static-typing

I have a `jenkins.gdsl` file defining some bindings I'm using in my Groovy script. In addition, I'd like to use the `@TypeChecked` annotation on my methods to get some guarantees about built code.

My `jenkins.gdsl` file looks like:

```
contributor(context(scope: scriptScope())) {
 // some definitions
}
```

And then my `script.groovy` looks like:

```
@TypeChecked(extensions='jenkins.gdsl')
void doStuff() {
  // ...
}
```

IntelliJ IDEA autocomplete works, but when building my project I get an error in my `jenkins.gdsl` file:

```
Error:Groovyc: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.codehaus.groovy.transform.stc.GroovyTypeCheckingExtensionSupport.scriptScope() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
```

Removing `(extensions='jenkins.gdsl')` gets rid of this error, but then I lose my GDSL definitions when building, so that's a no-go.

It feels like the solution would involve bringing in IntelliJ's [standardDsls](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/tree/master/plugins/groovy/groovy-psi/resources/standardDsls). I am not at all sure how to do this, or whether it is in fact the correct approach.

Answer (score 1):

`@TypeChecked` is a Groovy compiler annotation that can run some code during compilation.

But gdsl is an IntelliJ IDEA-specific script that's used only by the IDE to provide some completion and other coding assistance. It doesn't have anything in common with the compiler, and neither of those know anything of each other. So you can remove the `extensions` value, as it won't provide any typechecking during compilation.